# ARM Template undocumented resource type?

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I am looking at a deployment in a Resource Group and I see a resource of type 'Microsoft.Web/sites/host' was deployed successfully. If I click on this resource it should open the resource page, but instead it throws the "Resource not found" message. It does this even on a fresh deployment, fresh as completed successfully seconds ago.

I am looking for some documentation on this, but looks like there is none.
I can tell it should be a child type resource having a Microsoft.Web/sites as parent.
The resource is not present in the ARM template.

Any idea on what this is?

Comment: Could help us in sharing more information like what are the resources you are trying to deploy through your ARM template and adding the Sample ARM template (excluding the Personal Information) would help us to understand what is the issue here ? Help us with the screenshot which has "Microsoft.Web/sites/host" from the portal

Comment: @VenkateshDodda-MSFT Others have reported the same and there is a little discussion at the following link and the links within. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/351581/undocumented-arm-type.html